# Why does the count variable in my function not increment?

Tags: c, function

My function notFull(classc,reservations) doesn't seem to return a 0 at all

```
if(notFull(classc,reservations)==0 )
     {
        printf("%s class is FULL.Would you like %s class\n?", classc==1? "First":"Economy",classc==2? "First":"Economy");
        scanf(" %c",&ans);

        if(ans=='Y'||ans=='y')
           classc==1? classc=2:classc==2;
        if(ans=='n'||ans=='N')
           {
              printf("Next flight is in 3 hours\n");
              return 0;
           }
```

It seems that the count variable in my function notFull doesn't seem to increment.As such, it always returns 0.

```
    int notFull(int classp,int reservationsp[])



    {
        int start,end,i=0,count=0;

       if(classp==1)
       {
           start=1,end=5;
       }
       else if(classp==2)
       {
           start=6,end=10;
       }

    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    { 
       if(reservationsp[i]==1)
       ++count;

      printf("%d\n",count);   //To check if count actually incremented                  


      if(count==5)
      return 0;
      else
      return 1;

   }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as exact input, expected output and actual output. There are some code paths in `notFull` that can result in `start` being used without being set. But we can't tell for sure without complete code.

Comment: Also, the `if(count==5)` is **inside** the `for` loop. Looks like it should be outside otherwise the loop will immediately return `1` on the first iteration.

Comment: `for(i=start;i<=end;i++)` iterates only once due to `if(count==5)
          return 0;
          else
          return 1;`

Comment: `classc==1? classc=2:classc==2;` why not `if (classc == 1) classc = 2;`?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, it seems that `if(count==5)` being in the for loop itself was the problem

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin using the ?: in this case seemed to not compromise much readability

Comment: @Leon, I apologize for not being clear. It's not that it hurts anything, it doesn't, it just appears (along with other like code in the question) to be a superfluous use of the *ternary* operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that count has to increment, or it would never equal five, to cause a zero return.
But, you are always returning from the first time through the loop, so your function is certainly not doing what you think it is.
The ternary expression is also completely confused.
Pay more attention to the lesson, this homework needs lots of help.

Comment: Thanks but may I know why the ?: is confusing. I only used it as it was a short statement. The if-else would have been unnecessarily long.

Comment: classc==1? classc=2:classc==2  is just tortured.  What are you trying to do?